# How to add JFreeChart controls to NetBeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, jfreechart

I just want to know if there is any way of adding [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/) controls in [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), like Swing controls. It would be of great help if I could drag and drop charts instead of coding them.

Comment: Copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be added as controls in Swing controls Toolbox.

They can only be added as libraries to help you in auto completion and documentaion (http://www.coderanch.com/t/105259/vc/Add-JFreeChart-libraries-Netbeans)

Linked to - [How to display a JFreeChart in a NetBeans project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969203/how-to-display-a-jfreechart-in-a-netbeans-project)