# Adding a simple JFreeChart chart into a JPanel (netbeans gui)

Tags: netbeans, jpanel, jfreechart

I'm fairly new to Java and I've been trying to put a JFreeChart in a JPanel. I've finished the tutorial exercises where you generate a simple chart (with its own application window):

`TimeSeriesChartDemo1`

[image]

However I'm working on a larger group project that requires me to put the chart to be in a JPanel rather than its own window. The problem is I have no idea how to move from here, I also do not have the NetBeans IDE.

1. What do I have to put in `initComponents()` to initialize the JPanel?
2. Do I still have two files `JFreeChartDemo.java` and `NetBeansGUI.java` or is it all in one file?

If more information is needed please comment below.

For reference, I've cited a generic `XYPlot` example:

- API: [`TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170811142345/http://www.jfree.org:80/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html)
- Source: [`TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910182855/http://www.jfree.org:80/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html#line.65)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `initComponents` just initialize the JPanel (you can find plenty of information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)). Once you have done that, all that you should do would be to add your chart to the `JPanel`. Once you have done that, just add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame` you are working with.

So I am assuming you have something like so:

`public class JFreeChartDemo extends JFrame`

You should be able to get most of the work done if you do this:

`public class JFreeChartDemo extends JPanel`

This should allow you to re-use most of the initialization code, such as setting the size and location of the panel. You will however have to remove any JFrame related code from there.

Finally, you should keep two seperate source files, one for the chart and one for the rest. I am assuming that in the `NetBeansGUI` class you are doing the rest of the GUI stuff, so you in your `initComponent` (in `NetBeansGUI`) you could also have:

```
...
JFreeChartDemo jfd = new JFreeChartDemo()...
...
this.getContentPane().add(jfd)
```

In this case I am also assuming that `NetBeansGUI` extends `JFrame`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Sorry this is my first time working with gui stuff. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969203/how-to-display-a-jfreechart-in-a-netbeans-project (is this a close solution)?

Comment: @meiryo: I think that that answer does provide a good solution. My recommendation would be to try it out yourself. Also, I have noticed that you have updated your answer and if memory serves me right, `ApplicationFrame` might be something Netbeans related, so you might want to stick to more *traditional*, if you will, components such as `JFrame` and `JPanel` (unless you can't really do otherwise). This will make your component more shareable if you will, since it will use already available libraries.